# How to make IIS 7 pass all requests to asp.net

Tags: iis-7, asp.net-mvc

I have IIS 7 running an ASP.NET MVC application

I would like all URLs, regardless of any extension (eg *.csv, *.xml) to be handled by asp.net (ideally just going through the normal MVC rooting).

I used to be able to do this (using a wild card mapped to aspnet_isapi.dll I think), but IIS that was in an older version of IIS.

In this version of IIS (7.5.7600), it complains about "module required by this handler is not in the modules list...", even if I just try and copy existing rules, for say .ashx

I basically want to build and serve xml, csv and other files  dynamically. It works as long with different paths (e.g. /csv) but I can't get .csv to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9925346/get-net-to-handle-all-requests-in-iis7)

Set application pool in integrated mode and set that all request run all managed modules

```
<system.webServer>
  <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
  ...
  </modules>
  ...
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: thanks... that was me... two years ago... i will tattoo runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" on my arm

Comment: lol, I did not notice that :)

Comment: Awesome! @zod is awarded the `Amnesia` badge :-)